# Alter specific array values based on others in same "row"

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, calculated-field, array-walk

I am trying to perform a transformation/calculation on values in a returned SQL object, based on other values in the same row.  I cannot find a good reference for this, perhaps I just don't know what I'm looking for; it seems most functions (e.g array_walk) are for applying the same transformation to all values in an entire array? I want to alter just certain values, conditionally.

Here is my simplified attempt; doesn't work, but I think shows what I'm trying to do:

```
//------CREATE OBJECT-------//
$sql2 = "select internalname, value, adjboolean, adjfactor
         FROM superfilters WHERE id > '0'";

$filterobject = $DBLink->query($sql2);

//------MODIFY OBJECT------//

$input1 = 350;
$input2 = 175;

foreach ($filterobject as $row){
    if ($row['adjboolean'] = 1) {
        $row['value'] += ($row['value'] * ($input1 / $input2 - 1) * $row['adjfactor']);
    }
}
```

After trying to modify, no errors are thrown, but there is no effect on my row value.  I'd prefer to over-write, not create a duplicate array/object, but I could create new if necessary to perform the function.

Huge thanks for any help!

----EDIT----
Ok, so I have now learned that foreach actually works on a copy of my $filterobject, and I must reference in order to modify the actual result object.  It seems the following should work

```
    foreach ($filterobject as &$row){
```

However, I get the error "An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference".  So, now I'm working on that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `&` to let `$row` be updated by reference, otherwise it will get overwritten each time you loop and won't persist outside of the foreach.

Also, I assume your `adjboolean` check should be a comparison rather than an assignment? Use `==` instead of `=`.

```
foreach ($filterobject as &$row){
    if ($row['adjboolean'] == 1) {
        $row['value'] += ($row['value'] * ($input1 / $input2 - 1) * $row['adjfactor']);
    }
}
```

FYI, `array_walk()` will walk as well, you will just need to `use` your external variables to allow them to be accessible inside the callback's scope:

```
array_walk(
    $filterobject,
    function(&$row, $key) use($input1, $input2) {
        if ($row['adjboolean'] == 1) {
            $row['value'] += ($row['value'] * ($input1 / $input2 - 1) * $row['adjfactor']);
        }
    }
);
```

[Examples here](https://eval.in/385863).

Comment: Don’t forget `unset($row);` after that `foreach` loop, otherwise you might get unexpected side effects if `$row` is accessed elsewhere in the following code.

Comment: OK, so I figured out the reference issue at the same time scrowler was posting (thanks Scrowler).  However as you can see in my edit, it left me with another issue, which I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for the examples, Scrowler, they were helpful.  There must be something goofy with my $filterobject; code from your examples is not working for me; foreach approach returns the fatal error I mentioned, array_walk seems to fail, but with no error returned.

Comment: @Wavelength it'll be because of the data type returned from your DB query. Without knowing which driver you're using it's hard to suggest a fix, but a 'hack' would be to do this after your query call: `$temp = []; foreach ($filterobject as $row) { $temp[] = $row; } $filterobject = $temp;` to force it as a standard PHP array. Past that, try `var_dump`ing `$row` to examine its properties.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you, scrowler!  Casting as array and get_object_vars were both failing, but that little hack combined with referencing does the trick.  I will have to figure out what's going on with my result object.